# Ncurses Keyboard input

Tags: c, linux, input, keyboard, ncurses

I tested `getch` and `getchar` but it is waiting for input, I think there must be a function which reads the keyboard buffer. Part of my code

```
while (1) {
    if (key!='r')
    {
        if (key!='q')
        { 
            mvprintw(LINES-2, 1, "Display will refresh in %2d seconds", t);
            refresh();  
            sleep(1);
            t--;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
        exit (0);
        }
    }
    else
    {
    return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `read(1, buffer, buffer_size)` ?

Comment: @Eregrith: it's often *not* a good idea to mix `curses` stuff with normal stuff. Bypassing `curses` will often leave it in a state where it's confused. That's *certainly* true for output and may well be so for input as well (I haven't tested but, if there's a `curses` alternative to normal functions, it's probably better to use it).

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want `getch()` to wait, you have to set it up to be non-blocking, with `nodelay()`.

After executing:

```
if (nodelay (pWin, 1) == ERR) {
    // some error occurred.
}
```

then `getch()` will return `ERR` if no input is available.

The manpage for the input options is [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/curs_inopts) and the behaviour of `getch` is mentioned both there and in its own manpage as well, link [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getch).

---

> `int nodelay(WINDOW *win, bool bf);`
>
> The `nodelay` option causes `getch` to be a non-blocking call. If no input is ready, `getch` returns `ERR`. If disabled (`bf` is `FALSE`), `getch` waits until a key is pressed.

The window argument is the `curses` window that you want to effect this setting on.

---

> In no-delay mode, if no input is waiting, the value `ERR` is returned.

Comment: hey i have solved it with     nodelay(stdscr, TRUE); and 
 keypad(stdscr, TRUE); noecho();

Comment: What the hell is a pWin?

Comment: @AnnoyinC: if you use relatively common rules for variable names, and if you follow the links I gave, you should see that it's a pointer to a window, `WINDOW *` :-) It's a standard `curses` thing but I'll try to make that clearer.

Comment: I see, I tried to submit an edit earlier today outlining that passing `stdscr` as `WINDOW*` parameter immediately `nodelay`s the current terminal window.