# How to use scanf without stopping the program C language?

Tags: c, input, counter

I'm doing a counter where I'm showing how many seconds the user has to make the input. The problem is that when I use scanf(), the program will stop and will wait for the answer, but I don't want that. I'd like to keep running the counter even thought the user doesn't put anything.

Example:

```
for(int i=10;i>=0;i--){
            i==0? printf("time over\n"):printf("%d seconds left\n",i);
            scanf("%s", decision);
            sleep(1);
        }
```

What can i do to solve this?

Comment: you have to use threads to implement that

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @mangusta On Linux, you can do non-blocking IO on `stdin`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717572/how-do-you-do-non-blocking-console-i-o-on-linux-in-c

Comment: This won't be easy.  Using threads is one way, although not the only way.  You could also look into doing immediate, nonblocking, character-at-a-time input.  (This would *not* involve `scanf`!)

Comment: Using `select, pselect, poll or epoll` and then polling a set of file descriptors with a timeout set is one way, manually using signal handlers is another. `scanf` doesn't even enter the running.

Comment: Under a Unix-like OS, you could (1) put the terminal in 'cbreak' mode, (2) print the remaining time, (3) poll the input for one character if available, (4) display (echo) the character if you got one, (5) sleep for a second or so, and (6) loop back to (2).  It would be a fun little program to write.  You cold probably use [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) to good effect.

Comment: Style comment: don't use a ternary operator when an `if` / `else` is more appropriate, which is definitely the case with the first line in the body of the loop.  Use the ternary operator when you assign its result, or perhaps if you test its result (and I mean the result of the overall operator, not the result of the condition which is always tested, of course).

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208296/ncurses-keyboard-input

Answer (score 2):

Like mentioned in the comments one possibility would be to use poll.

`man poll` says:

> poll() examines a set of file descriptors to see if some of them are
>   ready for I/O or if certain events have occurred on them.

In code it could look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/poll.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main() {
    struct pollfd fds[1];
    fds[0].fd = STDIN_FILENO;
    fds[0].events = POLLIN;

    bool dataAvailable = false;
    for (int i = 10; i >= 0 && !dataAvailable; i--) {
        switch (poll(fds, 1, 1000)) {
            case -1:
                perror("poll failed");
                exit(1);
            case 0:
                printf("%d seconds left\n", i);
                break;
            default:
                dataAvailable = true;
        }
    }

    if (dataAvailable) {
        //read from stdin
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "no input\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's awesome, but only one thing more that i'd like to do. When scanf is invoke, the message of the seconds that appears after, move the cursor of the console and it doesn't let me see the whole string that i want to put. how can i solve this?                                                                    example :                                                                                                                             `10 seconds left
my str9 seconds left
ing is 8 seconds left
thi7 seconds left
s`

Comment: I'd use ncurses for a purpose like that. It would allow you to define text-based UI where you show countdown at a specific screen location in the terminal and the entry of the data in another one.