# How to immediately send input to program in C?

Tags: c

I would like to setup the input stream so that each character is sent immediately to the program instead of pressing enter every time. I've tried setting `stdin` to unbuffered mode with `setvbuf()`, and used `getchar()`, which I know isn't an unbuffered character input function but I had trouble with `getch()` since there's some sort of random character appearing on the screen without me touching the keyboard. And after I choose a valid option, the program just freezes, and I only changed `getchar()` to `getch()` when that happend, nothing else. I've been trying to figure this out for a while by asking small questions that lead me to the answer but I think I should just ask for help on my end goal. So does anyone know a way to send input to a C program immediately after pressing a key that's not enter?

Comment: This is OS dependent.

Comment: A simple solution to do what you want is to use specific library. If you want text program, you can use `ncurses`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9208296/1212012

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Capture characters from standard input without waiting for enter to be pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421860/capture-characters-from-standard-input-without-waiting-for-enter-to-be-pressed). Short version: It can not be done portably in C++ as this is OS dependent.

Comment: To present an answer with specificity, requires a question (problem statement) with specificity.  This can be achieved by simply including a [mcve]